# tengo un problema con unity y un .meta

Tags: c#, unity3d

desde no hace mucho empeze con unity a programar un juego fps 3d y cuando termine el codigo para poder lograr que camine me sale un error de un .meta acabo de empezar no se como arreglarlo ni lo que  es [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En realidad no es un error... solo es una advertencia informandote que Unity encontro un meta pero no encuentra el archivo al que el meta se refiere... posiblemente lo borraste o cambiaste de lugar

Lo unico que tienes que hacer es borrar el meta en la carpeta que te indica... es seguro ya que el meta referencia a un archivo cs